# Function keeps writing to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I have this collection on firebase

```
db.collection("userEventsCal/"+currentUserUID+"/activities")
```

and this adds an event object to the activities document. like this:

```
const event = {
    Time: eventTime,
    start: eventTimeDate,
    title: eventName,
    allDay: true
    
}

const currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid
const db = fire.firestore();

db.collection("userEventsCal/"+currentUserUID+"/activities").add({event})
```

My problem is that it keeps writing to firebase when I visit the events page.

```
const fetchGroupData = async () => {
        
        // I am going to fix this I just had to manipulate the string i know its bad I'll fix it
        const dateArray = eventDate.split(",");
        const day1 = dateArray[0];
        const day = day1.substring(0,3)
        const month1 = dateArray[1];
        const month2 = month1.split(" ");
        const date3 = month2[2];

        // final month
         const month3 = month2[1];
         const month = month3.substring(0,3);
        const year = dateArray[2];

        const newEventString = day + " " +  month + " " + date3 + year + " GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)";  
   

        const eventTimeDate = new Date(newEventString);
      
        const event = {
            Time: eventTime,
            start: eventTimeDate,
            title: eventName,
            allDay: true
            
        }
        allEvents.push(event)
      
        const currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid
        const db = fire.firestore();
        
        db.collection("userEventsCal/"+currentUserUID+"/activities").add({event})

    }
        
  }    
      
    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = false
        
        if(!mounted){
            fetchGroupData();
           
            }
                
                 return () => {
                     mounted = true
                 }
            
            }, [])
```

It keeps writing to firebase, how do I go about not adding an event when it already exists in the activites document.

The nested activities document looks like this with random doc.ids for each event:

[image]

It's basically adding multiple document id's for the same event

I have made a new collection and it is:

```
db.collection("userEventsCal4").doc(currentUserUID).collection(eventID).doc(currentUserUID).set({events: event})
```

in the page that I want to call it from, I don't ahve access to the eventID, so Im wondering if its possible to call just db.collection("userEventsCal4").doc(currentUserUID).get() to get everyrthing inside that collection?

Comment: You are indeed calling `fetchGroupData()` function every time in `useEffect()`

Comment: @Dharmaraj , but I need that to be called to get the events the first time?

Comment: If you want to know if a document is already present, then you will have to make a query to find out.  Using add() always creates a new document with a new random ID, so if you don't know that ID, then you can't use it to query to find out if it exists.  Maybe you don't want to use add() at all, or maybe you need to rethink how you are going about this work.

Comment: But as the name suggests `fetchGroupData` should only fetch the data. You can move the code that adds an event to another function e.g. `addEvent()` and call it when necessary?

Comment: if i change activites to eventID, how would i fetch      const qSnap = await fire
       .firestore()
       .collection('userEventsCal')
       .doc(currentUserUID)
       .collection(eventID)
       .get()

Comment: is it possible to just do fire .firestore() .collection('userEventsCal') .doc(currentUserUID).get() to get all the documents or

Comment: @emilysmyth your path `fire .firestore() .collection('userEventsCal') .doc(currentUserUID)` is pointing to  document and not a collection. You will only get the document and not the collection. To get all documents you need to point to a collection and then do the `.get()`